# AngularJs Filter event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

trying to make a scrollable horizontal image carousel in AngularJS which is coming along fine.  In my code I'm "scrolling" by changing the left position.  When I add a filter input box, I need to be able to reset the left position of my element that I'm scrolling.

I'm trying to understand the best way to do this in AngularJs

to see the problem:  [click here](http://www.netapps.net/movies).

you should get a bunch of movie posters to load.  hover your mouse over the carousel and scroll your mouse wheel down 5 or 6 times.

now type fast into the search box.  the left position of the list items is out of view.  I would have to click the left button a few times to see them.

I want to be able to reset the left position to 0 after the filter occurs.

thanks

Comment: i think you can use $anchorScroll for your requirement

Comment: probably not asking the right question. I modified my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is a hack but I used an event on the textbox onkeyup event to solve the problem.

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="search.Title" onkeyup="resetLeft()" /><img src="images/search.png" />

function resetLeft()
{
var obj = document.getElementById('carousel');
obj.style.left = 40;
}
```